# Can you find me a fake webcam/microphone with audio/video reset?

Tags: webcam, microphone

I want software that creates a fake webcam whose video can be restarted. I also want software that creates a fake microphone whose audio can be restarted. The restarts must happen simultaneously.

Any ideas? If this is unfeasible, can you recommend a fake webcam and microphone whose audio and video can be paused? The pauses must happen simultaneously.

Comment: What about using any video player app with a http output? vlc can do that.

Answer (score 0):

https://splitcamera.com

you can choose a video that will run as if you’re filming.

an illusion of being live

so you get video and audio

and then your microphone and webcam doesn’t work anymore but there source becomes the video that you choose

I see you’re trying to cheat your exams lmao

Comment: Really @Jhon? I cannot believe you...

Comment: have you tried it yet?